# How to apply expression in data table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

```
System.IO.StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(csvPath.Text);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table");
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date"));              
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A.TEMP090835"));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Difference"));

            while ((rowValue = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] arr;
                arr = rowValue.Split(',');
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Date"] = arr[0];
                row["A.TEMP090835"] = arr[4];
                row["Difference"] = //here is the problem
                dt.Rows.Add(row);

            }
            dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
            rdr.Close();
```

This code makes a data table with 3 columns.....Date, A.TEMP... and Difference. The csv file I'm importing the data from does not have the 3rd column which is "Difference". I need to write an expression for that column.....the logic for which can be understood through the following csv file:

Date, A.TEMP090835, Difference

10/28/2011, 25.56, 0

10/28/2011, 26.65, 26.65 - 25.56

10/28/2011, 27.11, 27.11 - 25.56

10/28/2011, 29.43, 29.43 - 25.56

10/28/2011, 30.29, 30.29 - 25.56

10/28/2011, 31.57, 31.57 - 25.56

10/28/2011, 32.82, 32.82 - 25.56

10/28/2011, 34.07, 34.07 - 25.56

How do I fill the "Diffrence" column ?

Comment: correction: row["A.TEMP090835"] = arr[1];

Comment: Does your CSV contains these -> `34.07 - 25.56` values in this format or you want to calculate it from `A.TEMP090835` and `Difference`?

Comment: in my csv, two columns are there. "Date" column and "A.TEMP090835" column.

Comment: i just showed the logic i want in the difference column to be built in the data table

Answer (score 0):

with a temp variable you can achieve

```
        System.IO.StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(csvPath.Text);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Table");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date"));              
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("A.TEMP090835"));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Difference"));
    double d=0;
        while ((rowValue = rdr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] arr;
            arr = rowValue.Split(',');
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Date"] = arr[0];
            row["A.TEMP090835"] = arr[4];
            row["Difference"] = Convert.ToDouble(arr[4])-d;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
    d=Convert.ToDouble(arr[4]);

        }
        dt.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
        rdr.Close();
```

not sure if you can do this with expressions by getting the previous row.

check this from o'reilly http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/05/26/datacolumn_expressions.html